# Trying to take conditional action with Calendar widget

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I need some guidance with handling a calendar widget in a website using Chrome (v 75.0.3770.142), Selenium Basic ChromeDriver (v 75.0.3770.140), Excel (2013) VBA.

I'd like to detect whether the date I wish to click is disabled or enabled.

This is because, if it's disabled, I need to tick another box in the website to enable it.

The trouble I'm having is how to detect whether the date is disabled or enabled.

**Here's the HTML for 2 scenarios:**

Scenario 1: If the date (in this example, the 1st of a month) is disabled:

```
<td class="ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled"><span class="ui-state-default">1</span></td>
```

Scenario 2: If the date (in this example, the 8th of a month) is enabled:

```
<td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="8" data-year="2019"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">8</a></td>
```

I've tried several approaches for example:

```
Obj.FindElementByXPath("//td[@class=' ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled ' and contains(., RDD_Cal_Date)]").IsPresent
```

This returns true whether the date is disabled in the calendar widget or not (RDD_Cal_Date is integer variable).

Comment: there are many date picker widgets it would be good if you can share url of page

Comment: unfortunately i'm unable to share since its a private page

Comment: is it possible to loop through all the displayed text in <td> tags with the same <span class...> and store in array?